# JAXB Unmarshalling having same XML elements and same attribute names but different attribute values into different Java objects

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have the following xml that has the same XML element `<child/>` and also same attribute name "action" repeated multiple times (possibly repeated 1000 times in this xml) - I want to unmarshal this xml, using JAXB (annotations or customer adapter), into multiple Java objects based on the value of the attribute "action".

For e.g. For all the "action" attribute value "Unchanged", I can map to List unchangedList object, for all the "action" attribute value "New" I would like to map to List newList and so on. Can we do that and how?

```
<parent>
   <child name="John1"  reason="12" action="Unchanged" />
   <child name="John2"  reason="12" action="Unchanged" />
   <child name="John3"  reason="12" action="New" />
   <child name="John4"  reason="12" action="New" />
   <child name="John5"  reason="12" action="Delete" />
   <child name="John6"  reason="12" action="Delete" />
   <child name="John8"  reason="12" action="Unchanged" />
   <child name="John9"  reason="12" action="Delete" />
   <child name="John10" reason="12" action="New" />
</parent>
```

Comment: Have you looked into `@XmlNamedObjectGraphs` and `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` you can define different proporder properties and add them during unmarshalling? Not sure if that's what are you looking but give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the question again and got an understanding of what you are asking and the following is the code that works perfectly for the XML you have provided. If incase you want some modification you can do accordingly in `Child.cass`

Parent.class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {
    @XmlElement(name = "child")
    List<Child> child;
}
```

Child.class:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Child {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String reason;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String action;

    @XmlAttribute
    List<String> unchangedList;

    @XmlAttribute
    List<String> newList;

    @XmlAttribute
    List<String> deleteList;

    private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller m, Object parent) {
        if (action.equals("Unchanged")) {
            unchangedList = new ArrayList<>();
            unchangedList.add(action);
        } else if (action.equals("New")) {
            newList = new ArrayList<>();
            newList.add(action);
        } else if (action.equals("Delete")) {
            deleteList = new ArrayList<>();
            deleteList.add(action);
        }
        action = null;
    }
}
```

JaxBMain.class:

```
public class JaxBMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Unmarshalling.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("action.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final Parent parent = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Parent.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(parent.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(parent, System.out);
    }
}
```

Following is the output you will get:

```
Parent(child=[Child(name=John1, reason=12, action=null, unchangedList=[Unchanged], newList=null, deleteList=null), Child(name=John2, reason=12, action=null, unchangedList=[Unchanged], newList=null, deleteList=null), Child(name=John3, reason=12, action=null, unchangedList=null, newList=[New], deleteList=null), Child(name=John4, reason=12, action=null, unchangedList=null, newList=[New], deleteList=null), Child(name=John5, reason=12, action=null, unchangedList=null, newList=null, deleteList=[Delete]), Child(name=John6, reason=12, action=null, unchangedList=null, newList=null, deleteList=[Delete]), Child(name=John8, reason=12, action=null, unchangedList=[Unchanged], newList=null, deleteList=null), Child(name=John9, reason=12, action=null, unchangedList=null, newList=null, deleteList=[Delete]), Child(name=John10, reason=12, action=null, unchangedList=null, newList=[New], deleteList=null)])
<parent>
   <child name="John1" reason="12" unchangedList="Unchanged"/>
   <child name="John2" reason="12" unchangedList="Unchanged"/>
   <child name="John3" reason="12" newList="New"/>
   <child name="John4" reason="12" newList="New"/>
   <child name="John5" reason="12" deleteList="Delete"/>
   <child name="John6" reason="12" deleteList="Delete"/>
   <child name="John8" reason="12" unchangedList="Unchanged"/>
   <child name="John9" reason="12" deleteList="Delete"/>
   <child name="John10" reason="12" newList="New"/>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class child { 
    public String name;
    public int reason;
    public String action;
}

public class parent { 
    public List<child> child;
}
```

Create your class in this way, once you have list then use java8 filter list method to get data with same value.

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding JAXB is to map an XML to a matching Java Object and vica versa. So what you try should not be done in JAXB as it's not suitable for these kind of modifications. Instead you should:

1. Transform your XML with XLST to the correct Object representation

or

2. Create an object representing your current XML and process it afterwards in java itself.